# How to set manual routes in Windows to tunnel all traffic over the VPN?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing

I'd like to route all traffic over a vpn, except for the actual vpn connection itself. I'm trying to work out what the underlying commands are that some the VPN clients do when then have established a connection (full tunnel, not split tunnel).

I understand the underlying trick they implement with 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 - : https://www.tinc-vpn.org/examples/redirect-gateway/

What I don't understand is what actual commands I should run.
I've tried:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 128.0.0.0 if 60
route add 128.0.0.0 mask 128.0.0.0 if 60
route add 52.59.92.187 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

In the interface column, I do notice it has '3c' and not the IP Address of the interface, but I don't know why that is there...

What commands should I run?

```
λ route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 16...00 ff 54 f0 df db ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #2
  3...d4 81 d7 2d d7 68 ......Realtek USB GbE Family Controller
 26...0a 00 27 00 00 1a ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3
 22...f8 63 3f 12 6e da ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  6...fa 63 3f 12 6e d9 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 60...00 ff 5a ea 2f 77 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 20...f8 63 3f 12 6e d9 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
 24...f8 63 3f 12 6e dd ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.16     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.109     50
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0        10.0.54.1               3c     38
     52.59.92.187  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.109     51
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0        10.0.54.1               3c     38
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.16    281
     192.168.0.16  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.16    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.16    281
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.109    306
    192.168.1.109  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.109    306
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.109    306
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
    192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
    192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
  192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.109    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link                3c    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.16    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.109    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link                3c    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.16    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why, but when I changed tinc from router mode to switch mode, I was able to set a gateway and everything was working as I expected.

Might be something to do with the TAP device.